# How do i change the font type of an existing text in a image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I have certain text in a image and i would like to change the font type to a specific font type such as Sans for OCR processing. Can anyone suggest me any software which can help me do that? The image i want to work on is below
[image]

I want it to look like this. i have tried GIMP but couldn't find anything that could help me change the font type.

[image]

Comment: It is just an image, you can't change a font based on a raster image data. If it was a layered photoshop/illustrator file, then there would be no problems.

Comment: @TomaszGolinski:- So, what do you suggest are my available options? I did OCR on the 2nd image and it was 100% accurate all the time. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are planning to achieve exactly in here. if the current OCR is 100% accurate, why bother to change the font on that image? Also, Is that something which will have to be automated? or every future picture will be handled manually? I guess you look for automated solution

Comment: This is a bit like asking "Somebody gave me some vanilla ice cream but I prefer chocolate ice cream, is there a way to take out the vanilla and put chocolate instead?" Once it's all been mixed together, the constituent parts lose their individuality and it can be very hard to get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you have is a raster image, there is no easy way to automate changing the font. A raster image is just that – an image. No font data or text is stored in a raster image. Only pixels.

If you want to change the text to make it readable by OCR then it isn't doable. The only way to automate this would involve some form of OCR, so if the OCR isn't accurate with the current font there isn't really much you can do other than manually re-type the text. Which probably defeats the whole point of the OCR.